# SQL to JPQL, How to query Nested JPQL

Tags: spring, jpa, jpql

I wonder if JPQL can be nested query. I am studying Spring Data JPA, and I also have uploaded several related questions.

If I have below sql in MySQL, how do I produce JPQL:

```
select
    c.*
from
    cheat c
    left join (select * from cheat_vote where val = 1) v on c.cheat_seq = v.cheat_fk
group by
    c.cheat_seq
having
    count(*) < 10
limit 5
```

I have two entities.

```
public class Cheat implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cheat_seq", length = 10)
    private Long cheatSeq;

    @Column(name = "question", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String question;

    @Column(name = "answer", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String answer;

    @Column(name = "writer_ip", nullable = false)
    private String writerIP;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "reg_date", nullable = false)
    private Date regDate;

    @Transient
    private String regDateText;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cheat", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<CheatVote> vote;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cheat [cheatSeq=" + cheatSeq + "]";
    }


}
```

Above entity has a @OneToMany collection, and the collection entity is below.

```
public class CheatVote implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name="seq", nullable=false)
    private Long seq;

    @Column(name="val", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private Integer value;

    @Column(name="ip_address", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private String ipAddress;

    @JoinColumn(name="cheat_fk", referencedColumnName="cheat_seq")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @NonNull
    private Cheat cheat;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CheatVote [seq=" + seq + "]";
    }


}
```

I want to get Cheat entitiy which has less than 10 children CheatVote entities.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Actually I couldn't...just googled it.  "SELECT c FROM Cheat c JOIN (SELECT v FROM CheatVote v WHERE v.cheat = c ...)" doesn't make sense! Because SELECT c FROM Cheat c join c.something would be right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Cheat c LEFT JOIN c.vote v WHERE v.value = 1 GROUP BY c.cheatSeq HAVING count(c) < 10")
```

About 'LIMIT' you can use parameter `Pageable` of Spring Data JPA

Comment: Execuse me, one more question..., I don't exactly understand the HAVING clause. in this sql, does that mean that there are grouped rows,. and one group has less than 10 rows? or the number of every grouped rows should be less than 10? I think it is maybe first one.. am i right?

Comment: All rows from table cheat_vote are grouped by cheat_seq. And each group has less than 10 rows

Comment: Sir, the answer might be wrong... because in my question, the WHERE clause(where val= 1) is applied before joining the two table, otherwise, as in your answer, I had put in action but, the WHERE caluse is applied after join... If I don't bother you, could you fix that answer..?

Comment: Two of them return the same result. Your query make the good performance than mine. I use this query because spring data jpa does not support join with sub query.

Maybe you can workaround with this:
@Query("SELECT c FROM Cheat c LEFT JOIN c.vote v ON v.value = 1 GROUP BY c.cheatSeq HAVING count(c) < 10")